# How can I perform a cyclic state transition when using discriminated-unions's Match to represent state transitions in C#?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, state-machine, state-pattern

I'm experimenting with using discriminated unions in C# (specifically, [using the excellent `OneOf` library](https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf)) as means of representing and performing state transitions, taking advantage of compiler-enforced type-safety and `OneOf`'s `Match` method.

This works fine for directed acyclic state transition graphs, like so:

#### State transition graph:

```
A -> B -> C1 -> D1 -> E
             -> D2
       -> C2 -> D3
```

#### State types

```
// state-specific constructors, fields and methods removed for brevity:

class A {
    public B Next();
}
class B {
    public OneOf<C1,C2> Next();
}
class C1 {
    public OneOf<D1,D2> Next();
}
class C2 {
    public D3 Next();
}
class D1 {
    public E Next();
}
class D2 {
    public E Next();
}
class D3 {
    public E Next();
}
class E {
    // Terminal state
}
```

#### Example state machine function:

```
public E Run( A initialState )
{
    A a = initialState;
    B b = a.Next();
    return b.Next().Match(
        ( C1 c1 ) =>
        {
            return c1.Match(
                d1 => d1.Next(),
                d2 => d2.Next()
            )
        },
        ( C2 c2 ) =>
        {
            D3 d3 = c2.Next();
            return d3.Next();
        }
    );
}

// or, more succinctly:

public E Run( A initialState )
{
    return initialState
        .Next()                  // A -> B
        .Next()                  // B -> C1 | C2
        .Match(
            c1 => c1.Match(      // C1 -> D1 | D2
                d1 => d1.Next(), // D1 -> E
                d2 => d2.Next()  // D2 -> E
            ),
            c2 => c2
                .Next()          // C2 -> D3
                .Next()          // D3 -> E
        );
}
```

The use of `.Match()` means the compiler requires the program to explicitly and exhaustively handle all possible types of values without also needing to rely on inheritance/polymorphism (as with the original State pattern).

But there's some problems:

- This is effectively a strict forward-only directed tree structure, even if the state machine graph converges to a linear state transition at the end, so if a single state is enterable from multiple other previous states (e.g. from `D1`, `D2` and `D3` to `E`) then the code to enter into state `E` is repeated 3 times (as seen with the `d1.Next()`, `d2.Next()`, and `d3.Next()` call-sites.
- This approach does not work for *cyclic* state transition graphs, and most state-machines tend to be cyclic.

#### State transition graph:

Consider this state transition graph that shows cycles (represented by duplicate node names - I'm not good at ASCII art), like so:

```
A -> B -> C1 -> D -> E
             -> A
       -> C2 -> B
```

And these state types:

```
class A {
    public B Next();
}
class B {
    public OneOf<C1,C2> Next();
}
class C1 {
    public OneOf<D,A> Next();
}
class C2 {
    public B Next();
}
class D {
    public E Next();
}
class E {
    // Terminal state
}
```

...and if I used same-scope `if` statements with `OneOf.TryPick` instead of `OneOf.Match` (which means we lose compiler-enforced exhaustive checks) and have to use `goto` (the horror):

```
public E Run( A initialState )
{
    A a;
stateA:
    a = initialState;
stateB:
    B b;
    b = a.Next();
    OneOf<C1,C2> bNext = b.Next();
    if( bNext.TryPickT0( out C1 c1, out _ ) )
    {
        OneOf<D,A> c1Next = c1.Next();
        if( c1Next.TryPickT0( out D d, out _ ) )
        {
            return d.Next();
        }
        else if( c1Next.TryPickT1( out a, out _ ) )
        {
            goto stateA;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
    }
    else if( b.Next.TryPickT1( out C2 c2, out _ ) )
    {
        b = c2.Next();
        goto stateB;
    } 
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

This is just ugly - from the use of `goto` to the necessary `else { throw` parts to prevent the compiler complaining about possible returns - but it has the (only) advantage of keeping program flow entirely within the `Run` function to avoid mutating object instance state (as opposed to only mutating in-scoped locals, making it inherently thread-safe) - this also has advantages in `async` code as the object that represents the `async` state-machine is kept simpler.

There exists an alternative by using `switch` with an enum type (which is bad, because I don't want to have to maintain an `enum` to represent the state classes I already defined) - or C# 7.0 pattern-matching `switch` (at the cost of requiring to downcast to `Object` and use runtime type information for the `switch` to work and the fact the compiler won't verify the switch is exhaustive, so new states could be added by another programmer and the code below would still compile (because the `Match` calls were replaced with `Value` because the Match's per-member lambdas would just return the state value):

```
public E Run( A initialState )
{
    Object state = initialState;
    while( true )
    {
        switch( state )
        {
        case A a:
            state = a.Next();
            break;
        case B b:
            state = b.Next().Value;
            break;
        case C1 c1:
            state = c1.Next().Value;
            break;
        case C2 c2:
            state = c2.Next().Value;
            break;
        case D d:
            state = d.Next().Value;
            break;
        case E e:
            return e;
        default:
            throw new InvalidOperationException( "Unknown state: " + state?.ToString() ?? "null" );
        }
    }
}
```

So - is there a way to logically jump between states without needing to satisfy the compiler with exceptions, `default` and `else` cases?

Comment: Just a small suggestion: Your link to the OneOf library isn't working you are missing the `f` at the end.

Comment: @RobinB Thank you for letting me know, it's fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's true that a state-machine *can* be modeled by the state of an imperative function, the result is code that is painful to read, and can be generalized by the `switch( state )` pattern exemplified in my initial post's final code sample.

I realized that the solution is to use `AnyOf` to also represent the present state, using its `Match` method to handle entering a specific state regardless of the previous state - and any specific state transitions can be handled when they happen in a type-safe manner.

So using the same example of a cyclic state machine from above:

Graph:

```
A -> B -> C1 -> D -> E
             -> A
       -> C2 -> B
```

Types:

```
class A {
    public B Next();
}
class B {
    public OneOf<C1,C2> Next();
}
class C1 {
    public OneOf<D,A> Next();
}
class C2 {
    public B Next();
}
class D {
    public E Next();
}
class E {
    // Terminal state
}
```

Can be safely implemented as:

```
using AnyState = OneOf<A,B,C1,C2,D,E>; // for brevity

public E Run( A initialState )
{
    AnyState state = initialState;
    E terminal = null;
    while( terminal == null ) )
    {
        state = state.Match(
            a  => AnyState.FromT0( a .Next() ), // B
            b  => b.Next().Match(
                    c1 => AnyState.FromT2( c1 ),
                    c2 => AnyState.FromT3( c2 )
                )
            }
            c1 => c1.Next().Match(
                    d => AnyState.FromT4( d ),
                    a => AnyState.FromT1( a )
                )
            }
            c2 => AnyState.FromT2( c2.Next() ), // B
            d  => AnyState.FromT4( d .Next() ), // E
            e  => AnyState.FromT5( terminal = e  )
        );
    }
}
```

Taking further advantage of `OneOf`'s `implicit` operator, this can be simplified to:

```
using AnyState = OneOf<A,B,C1,C2,D,E>; // for brevity

public E Run( A initialState )
{
    AnyState state = initialState;
    while( !( state.IsT5 ) ) )
    {
        state = state.Match<AnyState>(
            a  => a .Next(),    // B
            b  => b .Next()     // C1 | C2
                .Match<AnyState>(
                    c1 => c1,
                    c2 => c2
                ),    
            c1 => c1.Next()      // D | A
                .Match<AnyState>(
                    d => d,
                    a => a
                )
            c2 => c2.Next(), // B
            d  => d .Next(), // E
            e  => e
        );
    }
}
```

And we can replace the *magic* `IsT5` with an extension method to indicate terminal state, provided the last element of `OneOf` is used for terminal states:

```
static Boolean IsTerminal<T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5>( this OneOf<T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5> state )
{
    return state.IsT5;
}
```

Giving:

```
using AnyState = OneOf<A,B,C1,C2,D,E>; // for brevity

public E Run( A initialState )
{
    AnyState state = initialState;
    while( !state.IsTerminal() ) ) )
    {
        state = state.Match<AnyState>(
            a  => a .Next(),    // B
            b  => b .Next()     // C1 | C2
                .Match<AnyState>(
                    c1 => c1,
                    c2 => c2
                ),    
            c1 => c1.Next()    // D | A
                .Match<AnyState>(
                    d => d,
                    a => e
                )
            c2 => c2.Next(), // B
            d  => d .Next(), // E
            e  => e
        );
    }
}
```

And this can probably be packed-up as a universal state-machine extension on-top of `OneOf`.